# Range("My_Name") fails after enabling editing

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that is Macro Enabled.
In the 'ThisWorkbook' area I have a routine to check where users can click.
Here is an excerpt of the code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

Dim WhichNumbers As String
Dim WhichData As String
Dim WhichStatuses As String
Dim ToAddress As String
Dim CCAddress As String
Dim sFound As String
Dim wsTemp As Workbook
Dim sThisQuoteNumber As String
Dim pdfShell As Object

If sh.Name = "Report" Then
' If we intersect with one of the Quote Numbers, then present him with a view of the PDF of the quote.
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("QuoteNumber")) Is Nothing And (Selection.Count = 1) Then
    iRow = Target.Row
 .....
```

Here is what is happening:
This code all works fine.
I email the file to another user, when he opens it in email, OR if he saves it on his drive and opens it the file looks fine, but has the message at the top saying that you have to enable editing.
When you hit the 'enable' button, the program halts with an error indicating that the Range("QuoteNumber") method fails.
The message box allows you to "end" or "Debug".
If you hit 'End', then the message box clears, and the program works OK from this point on.

Any idea what is happening?  How do I stop this from happening so it doesn't 'blow-up' if my users' faces?

Rich

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure, you defined the Named Range "**QuoteNumber**" as a Workbook Scope, right ? Also, "**QuoteNumber**" Range is in this WorkBook.

I defined "**QuoteNumber**" as a WorkBook scope, and it's Range is in "**Repot**" Sheet, I used Range(A1:C10).
When I emailed this Workbook (with the code below attached), and my collegue (on his PC) clicked on one of the cells inside Range(A1:C10) in "**Report**" Sheet (cell B3), he got my test `MsgBox` of "Row number is 3".

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

Dim WhichNumbers As String
Dim WhichData As String
Dim WhichStatuses As String
Dim ToAddress As String
Dim CCAddress As String
Dim sFound As String
Dim wsTemp As Workbook
Dim sThisQuoteNumber As String
Dim pdfShell As Object

If sh.Name = "Report" Then
    ' If we intersect with one of the Quote Numbers, then present him with a view of the PDF of the quote.
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("QuoteNumber")) Is Nothing And (Selection.Count = 1) Then
        iRow = Target.Row
        MsgBox "Row number is " & iRow
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, my QuoteNumber is on this sheet and is scoped to Workbook.
When you emailed the file to your friend, did he get the message that you have to enable editing?  It is when you click the enable editing button that the error occurs.